# Google Chrome extension or userscript for showing unread Google Reader items in the favicon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Whenever I use Google Reader I pin its tab so only the favicon is visible. When I do this, the title of the page is, of course, not visible so I have no way of seeing how many unread Google Reader items I have. Is there any extension or userscript that will put the unread count in the favicon? Almost like how the [Stack Exchange Userscripts](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) will do this for unread chat messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google Reader Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apflmjolhbonpkbkooiamcnenbmbjcbf) extension will give you a Google Reader icon with a count that you can click in your extension section.  It was created by Google and is full-featured.